# How to prevent the pull request integration for SonarQube to report issues as inline comments on Githuib?

Tags: github, pull-request, sonarcloud

I configured SonarQube analysis to report it's status to pull requests on my GitHub project. SonarCloud already supports pull requests as first class citizen as described in https://blog.sonarsource.com/sonarcloud-loves-your-build-pipeline. As I understand, this kind of integration is not using the GitHub Plugin for SonarQube.

The configuration provides these properties ([look here for the complete configuration](https://github.com/BudgetFreak/BudgetFreak/blob/048832d40f47d12ea3b487238971439cc50ec059/gradle.d/600-sonarqube.gradle))

- sonar.pullrequest.provider
- sonar.pullrequest.github.repository
- sonar.pullrequest.branch
- sonar.pullrequest.key

The credentials for the technical user are set in the SonarCloud project administration.

You can see the results here: https://github.com/BudgetFreak/BudgetFreak/pull/86#pullrequestreview-125364230

Every issue is reported as an inline comment, one summary comment is made and the status is reported for the code-quality/sonarqube check.

I would like to disable the inline comment on every issue. This was possible using the GitHub plugin. Can this also be achieved with the new pull request integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, on SonarCloud, this feature is not available.